# JavaScript - removing element by part of id

Tags: javascript, html

I need remove the  `<div>` element on its `id`. I know that i can use function such as -

```
function removeElement(div_id) {
   var div = document.getElementById(div_id);
   element.parentNode.removeChild(div);
}
```

But the fact is that the `id` - composite. It consists of a constant part and part that change in every request. This part is a random set of numbers.

I know, i need to use regular expressions in this case. I would be most grateful for an example.

Comment: If you want to use jQuery then use can use this technique: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5002966/jquery-or-css-selector-select-all-ids-that-start-with

Comment: And you don't have a `className` in order to identify these elements?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how you can do this with pure JavaScript without any libraries:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
    forEach = Array.prototype.forEach,
    regex = /^foo.*$/;

forEach.call(divs, function (d) {
    if (d.id !== undefined && regex.test(d.id)) {
        d.parentNode.removeChild(d);
    }
});​
```

In the example above all div elements which ids start with `foo` will be removed.
Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/UemQ5/

Comment: Nice one, I was just about to post something similar just without regex.. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cmeYx/)

Comment: I'm glad that my answer is helpful. Best regards!

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to use a regex, you can use one of these 3 selectors, depending on what you need: **starts with**, **ends with**, or **contains**.

Starts with: `$("[id^=item]")`

Ends with: `$("[id$=item]")`

Contains: `$("[id*=item]")`

Or if they don't suit your needs, there's even more here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery selector regex to resolve it :)

read this :
http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

Answer (score 1):

1.**jQuery Attribute Starts With Selector**

On jQuery, "**Attribute Starts With Selector**" selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value beginning exactly with a given string.

```
  jQuery('[attribute^="value"]')
```

If you want to remove the divs which 'id' starts with "ABC_", your code goes something like this:

```
  $('div[id^="ABC_"]').remove();
```

The document is here
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/

2. **jQuery Attribute Ends With Selector**

Similarly,"**Attribute Ends With Selector**" selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value ending exactly with a given string.

```
  jQuery('[attribute$="value"]')
```

If you want to remove the divs which 'id' ends with "_ABC", your code goes something like this:

```
  $('div[id$="_ABC"]').remove();
```

The document is here
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/

3. **jQuery Attribute Contains Selector**

Lastly,"**Attribute Contains Selector**" Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing the a given substring.

```
  jQuery('[attribute*="value"]')
```

If you want to remove the divs which 'id' contains "ABC", your code goes something like this:

```
  $('div[id*="ABC"]').remove();
```

The document is here
http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Answer (score 1):

I think query selector would be best for you

```
function myFunction()
{

var matchedElements = document.querySelectorAll("#myContainer div[id^='prefix']");

var forEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

forEach.call(matchedElements, function (el) { el.parentNode.removeChild(el); } );

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/KLVP5/1/

Answer (score 0):

with [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) you can get elements via partial ID

look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368591/jquery-partial-selectors) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

In modern JS as by June'22 you can do it with one-liner:

`document.querySelectorAll("div[id^='myPrefix']").forEach((element) => { element.remove() })`

Also want to give credit to @Nikita's answer here, 'cause I find it the most accurate and effective of all here.