# Delete <tr> whose id contains a specific symbol

Tags: javascript, html

I decleared a `<table>` inside my JSP page. Using JavaScript, I want to delete all `<tr>`s whose `id` contains `;`.

For example:

```
<tr id=";1234;">
   ...
   ...
</tr>
```

The entire line must be deleted. Someone can give me a tip?

Comment: Those are invalid id attributes, i doubt most browsers will parse them with `;` character, to begin with.

Comment: how does your code look so far to solve your problem?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('[id*=";"]')`

Comment: Your IDs are not valid.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html

Comment: @E.Maggini well, they're valid in [HTML5 standard](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute), since they don't contain spaces, but if you're talking about backwards compatibility for HTML4, then sure...

Comment: By “the entire line” you mean “the entire element”, right? I’m certain, you don’t want code like this: `… </tr>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript - removing element by part of id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13949470/javascript-removing-element-by-part-of-id)

Comment: How about the </tr>'s ? Or better ... what is the problem you are trying to solve ? This makes little sense to me, sorry ...

Comment: @PatrickRoberts _"I want to delete all `<tr>`s"_ Should selector be `tr[id*=";"]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('tr[id*=";"]').forEach(node => node.remove());
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id=";1234;">
    <td>Remove Me</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Keep Me</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can programmatically remove all `<tr>` elements with an `id` containing a `;` by executing the following snippet:

```js
Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('tr[id*=";"]')).forEach(tr => {
  tr.remove()
})
```

Following links for reference:

- [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [attribute selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)
- [`Array.from()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [`Array#forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)
- [`ChildNode#remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

Comment: Note, `.forEach()` can be chained to `.querySelectorAll()` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36108712/foreach-method-of-node-childnodes

Comment: This is ECMA6 specific, no?

Comment: @E.Maggini It is, but only IE doesn't support it, and for that you can use a [transpiler](https://babeljs.io/).

Answer (score 0):

The EASIEST way to do this is as follows AND is cross-browser (non-ECMA6) compatible.

https://jsfiddle.net/dfju8xn8/1/

```
<table>
<tr id=";1234;">
<td>foo</td>
</tr>

<tr id="yadayada">
<td>moo</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and Javascript

```
var myElements = document.querySelectorAll('tr[id*=";"]');

for (var xx = 0; xx < myElements.length; xx++) {
   myElements[xx].outerHTML ='';
}
```

p.s. For readability sake, you should use one of the methods above. If you are going to have to iterate over a large result set, consider that for loops are tested as executing faster.

Comment: `myElements[xx].parentNode.removeChild(myElements[xx]);` is better.

Comment: @Xufox Could you explain why, please? Yours requires a call to the parent node, followed by a function call. Mine wipes the desired chunk of HTML directly.

Comment: Setting `innerHTML` or `outerHTML` isn’t just a simple string operation or property access. There’s lots of DOM-reparsing happening after that which is probably slower than a simple DOM node removal. There’s also the possible issue of [accidentally killing event listeners](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5113105/4642212). You _could_ also use `myElements[xx].remove()`, but you were talking about cross-browser compatibility. `outerHTML` actually has compatibility issues of its own and `remove` or `removeChild` is a much more intuitive method for what is being done here.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :)