# Get a (half)-dynamic css-class with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm kinda stuck right now. I need to get a certain class from an element. The class attribute could look like:

```
<div class="span12 display">
```

or:

```
<div class="span24 overview overview-small">
```

So the **span*** is always the same just the number can differ.

I really don't know how to get the **span*** everytime using jQuery.

**EDIT:**
My goal is to change the size of the element. e.g. from span12 to span18. It is possible that I need to change the size from span10 to span18 or from span8 to span18. That's why I'd prefer a generic solution.

So the number is quite random. And it's very important to know the span-number before changing it to span18 because it should be possible to change the previous size (span).

Sorry that I forgot to mention this. :|

Comment: Maybe a `data-span="12"` attribute would be better?

Comment: Can you not change the html and add your own class?

Comment: Adding a new attribute would work or giving all of those divs a related class. However a custom attribute would be best.

Comment: @Shmiddty - the span12 refers to the Bootstrap "span12". Setting a `data-span="12"` would be a workaround for me. But Thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: What do you mean by "get" a span? What are you actually trying to do here? That could mean a lot of things...

Comment: @Swordfish0321, sorry I forgot to mention this. I updated the question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Partial Selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368591/jquery-partial-selectors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple string parsing can get it for you: http://jsfiddle.net/7sXFb/

```
$("div[class*=span]").each(function(){
  var cls = this.className,
      prt = cls.split(" "),
      spn = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < prt.length; i++){
    if (prt[i].indexOf("span") > -1)
      spn = +prt[i].replace("span","");
  }

  console.log(spn);
});
```

You can add 10 like this:

```
this.className = this.className.replace("span" + spn, "span" + (spn+10));
```

Or, like so:

```
$(this).removeClass("span" + spn).addClass("span" + (spn+10));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have the number, it shouldn't be that hard.

```
var spanNumber = 15;
var spanSelector = ".span"+spanNumber;
var spanClassName = $(spanSelector)[0].className;
```

If you do not have the number, then you can look for a partial match and then do something with that group

```
var spans = $('div[class*=span]');
```

Perhaps iterate them:

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hFx26/

```
spans.each(function(index,element){
 var spanClass = element.className;
 var tar = spanClass.indexOf("span");
 var number = "";
 for( var i = (tar + 4); i < spanClass.length; i++ ){
  if( spanClass[i] == " " ) break;
  number += spanClass[i].toString();
 }
 number = parseInt(number);
 //call some function with number, element, or replace the className
});
```

Comment: He doesn't say so, but I assume the number is always different, and he probably doesn't have it.

Comment: Yen, the number is always different

Comment: @AndreZimpel - So you should go with the example which implements a partial match.

Comment: @Travis J - Yep, Shmiddty's solution works. But thank you anyway! :)

Comment: @AndreZimpel - I take it you did not read the section I posted "If you do not have the number".

Comment: @Travis J - I did read it. But I forgot to describe my Goal, which I did in the **EDIT:** section. Thank's for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could simply add another class like `allspans` to each element that has a span* value and use that as the selector.