# How to get class name starting with by using attribute?

Tags: jquery

Is there a way to get class name starting with class something as below:

```
$('#div:visible').attr('[class^=qest]')
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Partial Selectors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368591/jquery-partial-selectors)

Comment: How's that duplicate?

Comment: maybe duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579108/jquery-has-class-that-starts-with

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery attribute selector like this.

```
$('[class^=qest]').each(function() {
    alert($(this).attr("class"));
});
```

This will get all the elements with class name starts with 'qest' and then loop through each element.